# How can I open an App with Vuejs 3 if it is installed in phone?

Tags: vue.js

I have seen many comments about this topic but nobody has really answer the question, because I tried all these codes already and they did not work at all.

I know that I can add fb:// etc but if it is not a known app I mean example mercadolibre.com app how could I open it? because I have tried mercadolibre:// and it did not work... I have this code:

```
<!-- src/components/MercadoLibreButton.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
      <button @click="openMercadoLibre">Abrir MercadoLibre</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
      methods: {
      openMercadoLibre() {
      if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1){
         window.location.href = 
          'http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mercadolibre&hl=es_CL&gl=US';
       }
       if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") > -1){
          window.location.href = 
          'http://itunes.apple.com/lb/app/PACKAGEURL';
        }
      } 
    },
  };
  </script>
```

That code just opens the google play store but I need to open it's the app if it is installed, it same if you use netflix or something like that if you have the app it does not open the url it just opens the app.. so I wonder if somebody knows the code in VueJS 3. Thanks.

Comment: Well usually you have to know their deep-link inorder to do this, if they do have one it might be in the docs..

Comment: @MajedBadawi where can I see its deep link?

Comment: You should look into the docs of the app you're trying to integrate with, not all ones have it...